# The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I'm trying to upload an `Excel` file to a `SQL` database and was working fine on my computer, but once I uploaded to the server it's giving me this error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Book1.xls'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Here is my code:

> ```
>     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
>         using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
>         {
>             OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]"), connection);
>             connection.Open();
>             using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
>             {
>                 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=WSCJTCSQ1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test"))
>                 {                  
>                     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "CoaTest";                        
>                     bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("First Name", "fName");
>                     bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Last Name", "lName");
>                     bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Agency", "agency");
>                     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
>         Label1.Text = "Successfully Uploaded The New Roster";   
>     }
> ```

Comment: Can u show code that saved the file? Into what folder?

Comment: When I'm hosting it on my local machine it's just on the Desktop.  Should I save it to the server first and then pull it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string file = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath,
Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-",string.Empty));

FileUpload1.SaveAs(file)
```

Now in your import code

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file on the server before you connect to it, something like:

```
string sServerFilespec = ("C:\\ServerFolder\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.SaveAs(sServerFilespec);
```

Comment: -ve becuase this is not the good approach to access the server path. try using either Server.MapPath() or HttpRequest.PhysicalApplicationPath.